# Is the verb "türken" offensive?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, colloquial

In colloquial German we hear ***"türken"*** or more often ***"getürkt"*** used for *"to fake"*.

> *"Das sind doch alles getürkte Daten."*

Duden does not explain the origin of this verb but does not recommend it's usage:

> Es wird besonders von türkischstämmigen Mitbürger(inne)n als diskriminierend empfunden und sollte deshalb im öffentlichen Sprachgebrauch unbedingt vermieden werden.<sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tuerken)</sup>

Is it true that Turkish people feel discriminated by the usage of *"getürkt"*? From the meaning it seems hard to believe that *"türken"* had any etymologic relationship to Turkey or the Turkish culture. Is there anything known about that?

Comment: I've also once heard "Einen Türken bauen" (a deliverable for a European research project, where the real research interests were elsewhere).

Comment: Auch verboten: Kümmeltürk, Jubelperser, Negerkuss. Noch nicht verboten: Böhmische Dörfer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BCrken_%28Verb%29) has a bunch of possible origins for the verb "türken".

Multiple times (also in the discussion to the article) different wars against the Ottoman Empire (the turkish wars) are mentioned.
Appearently it was not uncommon to use those as false pretenses, hence a reasen was "getürkt".

There are also other possible origins that don't necessarily relate to Turkey or its people.

As usual, the origin of the term "etw. türken" is not clear. It is well possible, that it has developed from different origins in different places and has come to be understood as "to fake sth." everywhere.

---

Since I'm not Turkish and do not know anybody whom I could ask about feeling discriminated by this verb, I can not give a qualified answer.

But I would assume, that those who are fluent in German (die mit der Sprache vertraut sind) are not offended by the use of it, since they know that it is a term that has developed over the years and does not express a prejudice.

As @bernd_k mentioned, political corectness could be the reason for which Duden discourages using this verb.

Answer (score 9):

Die Herkunft des Begriffes beruht auf einem angeblichen Schachautomaten. Siehe [Abschnitt der Türke](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schachcomputer).

**Edit:**

Aus Sicht eines deutschen Sprechers wird es wohl wohl im Allgemeinen ohne diskriminierende Hintergedanken verwendet. Mir fallen auf die Schnelle außer dem Englischen "gefaked" keine Synonyme ein.

In Gegenwart von Türken sollte man höflicherweise auf die Verwendung verzichten.

Comment: Ist es nun diskriminierend oder ist der Duden Eintrag getürkt?

Comment: @Takkat Das ist vermutlich eine Frage der politischen Korrektheit. Eigentlich nicht, aber ...

Comment: *gefaked*? Brrr. Dann doch lieber *gefälscht* oder *unecht*.

Comment: @Musik das trifft es nicht ganz. Die Leistung der Schachmaschine (des verborgenen Schachspielers) war echt. Die Täuschung besteht darin, das der Anschein erweckt wurde, dass es sich um eine im Prinzip nachbaubare Maschine handelt.

Answer (score 3):

Die Frage hat drei Seiten, soweit ich sehe:

- ist es beleidigend gemeint?
- wird es als beleidigend aufgefasst?
- sitzt an der Wurzel des Begriffs eine Beleidigung?

Obwohl mir der Schachautomat bekannt ist, habe ich den Begriff nicht mit diesem in Verbindung gebracht, bevor ich bernd_ks Antwort las. Jetzt finde ich die Antwort zumindest plausibel.

Zuvor habe ich gedacht, der Begriff gehe auf Animositäten um die Zeit der Belagerung Wiens zurück – habe also eine beleidigende Herkunft vermutet.

Mir scheint, im rechtsradikalen Umfeld existiert eine große Vorliebe für den Begriff, so dass, obwohl die Herkunft vielleicht nichts Despektierliches hat, auf eine gegenwärtig herabsetzende Empfindung spekuliert wird.

Auch versehentlich ausgelöste Verstimmungen zu vermeiden, könnte also Anlass sein, auch heute den Begriff zu vermeiden, auch wenn sich zeigen sollte, dass er eine unverfängliche Geschichte hat.

Letzteres kann aber auch bezweifelt werden, denn wieso sollte die Nationalität des Spielers betont werden, und nicht dessen Haarfarbe, Religion, Vorname oder Schuhgröße? Wesentlich für das Gelingen der Täuschung wäre allein eine geringe Körpergröße. Dass die Redewendung nicht "gezwergt" heißt, könnte also dafür sprechen, dass sehr wohl eine bestimmt fremdenfeindliche Gesinnung den Begriff befördert hat.

Comment: Der Spieler im Schachautomaten wurde damals als Türke dargestellt. Vgl. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schacht%C3%BCrke): "Die Schachmaschine bestand aus einer **in türkische Tracht** gekleideten Figur eines Mannes (...)".

Comment: Hm. Ja, und? `Wieso wurde er als Türke dargestellt` wäre dann wohl zu fragen.

Comment: @elena nicht der Spieler _in_ der Maschine, sondern der künstliche Spieler, der _Teil_ der Maschine war, war in türkische Tracht gekleidet. Wie man auch eindeutig auf den Bildern im von dir verlinkten Artikel sieht.

Comment: @nem75 Stimmt natürlich, meinte ich eigentlich auch.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "türken" looks and sounds like "Turk," and MAY have origins in this word. As such, it would sound offensive to an American, at least one who was sensitive about not offending Turks.

A verb similarly avoided, at least in American English, is "gyp," which means to cheat, and may have links to either "gypsy" or Egypt.

And in America, we try to avoid using words like "niggardly" that even remotely sound like the "n-word."

All of the above is an American point of view, so I can't say how Germans might feel about these words.

Answer (score 3):

Über "türken" und "getürkt" kann man die merkwürdigsten Geschichten zur Erklärung lesen. Schachtürke, türkische Nationalhymne, Türkengefahr. Früher hatte de.wikipedia alle diese Geschichtchen. Jetzt haben sie den Artikel geändert.

Ich habe diese Geschichtchen nie ernst genommen. Ich habe mich lange und intensiv mit dem Ausdruck türken beschäftigt und bin der Meinung, dass türken mit Trick, tricksen, und Französisch truquer zusammenhängt.

truquer heißt heute fälschen, Wein: panschen, Bilanzen: frisieren. Es war aber früher auch ein Begriff, der im Theater verwendet wurde, wenn mit verborgenen Maschinerien und anderen Tricks auf der Bühne kunstvolle und überraschende Effekte erzeugt wurden. Eben das, was man heute im Filmbereich Spezialeffekte nennt. Trickaufnahme heißt heute noch im Französischen le trucage. *le truc* auch: Bereich Theater: Maschine zu Verwandlungen, Langenscheidt, Sachs-Villate, 29. Auflage.

Der Begriff truquer muss vom Militär übernommen worden sein. Für "Spezialeffekte" bei Manöverübungen wird im Militär türken und getürkt verwendet.

Das deutsche türken ist einfach französisch truquer mit Umstellung des r (r-Metathese), aus trük-en wurde türk-en. Warum hier r-Umstellung eintrat, das kann man nur vermuten. Es könnte sein, dass "trücken" dem Verb "drücken" zu ähnlich war.

Als Wikipedia noch diverse Geschichtchen über türken erzählte, habe ich den Leuten meine Hypothese (von der ich überzeugt bin) mitgeteilt. Das war vor einigen Jahren.
Heute habe ich Wikipedias neue Fassung gelesen. Einige unwahrscheinliche Geschichtchen haben sie inzwischen weggelassen. Französisch truquer haben sie jetzt auch erwähnt. Aber der Artikel ist immer noch nichts wert.

Viele Leute meinen, türken habe etwas mit der Türkei zu tun. Das ist eine völlig irrige Meinung. Trotzdem würde ich einem Türken gegenüber nicht gerade den Ausdruck türken oder getürkt verwenden. Denn er kann ja nicht wissen, dass das einfach tricksen/getrickst heißt und nichts mit seiner Nationalität zu tun hat.

http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BCrken_(Verb)