# Idiom: einen Türken bauen. Etymology?

Tags: etymology, idiom

What is the origin of the strange idiom "einen Türken bauen"?

I have already [checked wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einen_T%C3%BCrken_bauen), and they present a few alternatives. All these alternatices are insufficient IMO, as they all smell like someone invented them to make the idiom sound plausible.

These stories all are hard to refute, but I don't believe them.

Short overview:

> **Story 1:**
> When the "Kaiser-Wilhelm-Kanal" was inaugurated, the
> hymn of every State that had sent a representative was played. Because
> the hymn of the Turks was not available and instead the musicians
> played "Guter Mond, du gehst so stille durch die Abendwolken hin."
>
> **Story 2:**
> In the age of Rokoko Johann Wolfgang Ritter [..] built a so called "Mechanischer Türke"
> who won chess against some of the most renowned masters. Later it was revealed, that in
> fact the puppet did not think, but a human inside played.
>
> **Story 3:**
> Swiss Military speech: *Türgg* - maneuver
>
> **Story 4:**
> In the 15th to 17th century, there was great fear of a turkish invasion. This seems to have been used to create high taxes from nothing (to be used for a counter-invasion), which were used for something completely different then.

Comment: A few options are presented by wiktionary. http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einen_T%C3%BCrken_bauen

Comment: Please show some research effort... Jeff Atwood once wrote: "It's a privilege to be allowed to ask questions." [in his blog.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) If you ask questions that are looking like a "please google this for me" (please optional) you make people leave, and as I don't like that I downvoted you. This is meant as *incentive* to edit your question, not as punishment ;)

Comment: See also: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BCrken_%28Verb%29

Comment: I believe anyone on here will have to research the origin as well, as they are not clear.
Here is the Wiki link if you are interested: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einen_Türken_bauen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the verb "türken" offensive?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/is-the-verb-t%c3%bcrken-offensive)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its answer can be easily googled.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously my question will not lead to a discussion of the problem. So I'm going to add my story to those of wikipedia. I learnt the expression in the German Army in the sixties where it was currently used for special effects during manoeuvres. In my old French dictionary Sachs-Villatte the French noun truc with the general meaning
fraud is also indicated as a special theatre expression for machinery used to produce special effects on the stage, eg special transformations.
In my view the French military took over this theatre term for their similar devices
in manoevres and this term came to the German military as well. But it was transformed from truc over *Trück to  Türk, and finally to Türke, a simple metathesis of the sound r. So when a German officer said "man hat einen Türken gebaut" he meant the special effect was produced by tricks with specially built machinery and devices. He did not speak of a person from Turkey or a turc who played chess.

Comment: So you have your theory, which in my eyes is neither more nor less plausible than the ones already listed in Wikipedia. By this I mean it IS plausible. Add it to the Wikipedia list!

Comment: BTW, the most common colloquial meaning of _un truc_ (a trick) nowadays is _ein Ding_, so that _jdm einen Türken bauen_ would be _jdm ein Ding bauen_.

Comment: before you go and edit Wikipedia though, I will tell you that _truc_ really means _trick_, and it would have been hard for the meaning as theatrical machinery to overshadow the generic meaning outside of theaters.

Comment: Today the meaning of truc is a bit more harmless, but at first the meaning went from trick, dodge to fraud. And the expression "einen Türken bauen" did not come up in our generation, it is older. But it is up to you whether you want to believe the story of the chess turc, at least for wikipedia it was worth relating.

Comment: I don't understand why you despise the theory that the expression originates from the [Mechanical Turk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk)

Comment: I don't despise it, it find it improbabable. It is a pity I have not the means to check when the French military used the term, and when the German military used the term. Perhaps it would be possible to show that the expression was in use before the chess turc. But for me they story of the chess turc is etymologically no explanation. The use of "bauen" is a first indication.

Comment: I don't agree. But this would be and endless discussion. Have also a look at the link I posted as a comment to your question (Wikipedia instead of Wiktionary - I should have said Wiktionary in my previous comments...)

Comment: I have been studying this problem for years and know what wikipedia has written. But they have not found that French truc was also an expression for special theatre machinery.